# UIPageViewController Definition conflicts with previous value

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uipageviewcontroller

My App uses a `UIPageViewController`. I am getting a Definition conflicts with previous value error for my when i put in the following two functions

```
   func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        return nil
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        return nil
    }
```

These functions are needed in order to get rid of the "does not conform to `UIPageViewControllerDataSource`"

The complete code is:

```
import UIKit

class Root: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource  {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.dataSource = self
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        return nil
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show full code of the class and its extension.

Comment: Just updated there now, thanks.

Comment: @pete800 well, as it seems, that what I thought was a mistake in the question, was your actual mistake you should not accept my edit :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the functions from `viewDidLoad` and putting them to the class body :).

```
import UIKit

class Root: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource  {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.dataSource = self
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        return nil
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that :)

Comment: Glad to help :).